# What's the issue in following code that the control is not going inside if condition?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having an array named $users as follows:

```
$users = Array
(
    [d3c1ac9ac08da86e73258a11a43251af] => enable 
    [b993166c4795b3bfe96640e55e8dcbbc] =>  enable 
    [77d4721ada7677feda77a250c7cee1c4] =>  disable 
    [68d6e7a8c09c77c5fec49945beaea4f8] =>  disable 
    [85634bc9cdbcb6b39eaf4946b99db5de] =>  disable 
    [bb1a20794d65966b950c5933100496ce] =>  disable 
    [59ee376a9d126a26b350fff3110ea825] =>  disable 
    [428895b1ae5f3226345e6c6f256c7c85] =>  disable 
    [78a619902b22a1f17def5198179334be] =>  disable 
    [ab5ca5cbfd45c7bd0e0817b200597682] =>  disable 
    [2e0ae6cdce7647daf73d3d370a7a12f8] =>  disable 
    [867d3433169d05323a4ff350ca21b1c9] =>  disable 
    [3dddd9a46cfeb4e4d3607fb178113656] =>  disable 
    [ba908fd0f04f245c82ed379bd3f57285] =>  disable 
    [ec702094416ad4789288f3f64b3537a7] =>  disable 
    [cbb677ed11c1838281c6962d52f62b8a] =>  disable 
    [45a1e20492f043d404580becad029f12] =>  disable 
    [8b1acc0101378e60985f8200fa3900de] =>  disable 
    [f063e4cd1b86f389f2647c4211498615] =>  disable 
    [f3639eb674adbb243579942d3746044a] =>  disable
)
```

Now I'm having following loop:

```
foreach ($users as $id => $status) {  
  if($status == disable) { echo "Yes"; die;
    $objAdminUsers->UpdateUserStatus($id, $status); 
    $count++;
  }
}
```

My issue is when I'm traversing through the array one by one I'm not able to get inside the if condition. But when I put in individual array element the if condition works and everything works perfectly. Can you guide me why I'm not able to get inside the if condition while traversing throgh the array? The sample message I've written above in code also doesn't get echoed. Can you help me in this regard? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just fix your previous question, instead of opening new one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334022/how-to-integrate-two-for-foreach-loops-in-following-scenario

Comment: @Glavić:The scenario I'm having now is different so I didn't modified the existing question.

Comment: @Glavić:Yes, it's the value from array element.

Comment: @Glavić:I'm not getting any errors at all.

Answer (score 0):

**1) You failed at copy/paste from [previous/same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19334063/67332).**

2) Your `$users` array has values like `_disable` (*first char is space*) and not `disable`, thats why your `if` statement is not working. User @AmalMurali already wrote how to fix this in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19334063/67332); he even pasted a [demo](https://eval.in/54197), like:

```
$array = array_combine($user_ids, $user_statuses);
$array = array_map('trim', $array); // remove whitespaces
```

3) Turn on error reporting, so you can see your bugz.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

4) You probably don't have defined constant `disable`, so this:

```
if ($status == disable) {
```

is invalid, and if you had error reporting ON (as stated in point 3.), you would see notice like:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant disable - assumed 'disable'
```